# Change locale in CentOS 6.3

Tags: centos, localization

I want to change locale in CentOs 6.3 to English. But after changing, only root account have English interface... Another user still have Russian interface. But I changed locale to:

```
LANG="en_US.UTF-8"
SYSFONT="latarcyrheb-sun16"
```

inside `/etc/sysconfig/i18n` file. Also i tried to change it using GUI utility - `system-config-language`. After changes I always reboot my machine. Nothing help.

Thanks.

Comment: Is this a workstation where you are logging in at the desktop, or a server where you log in from console or remotely?

Comment: @MichaelHampton yes, is workstation at desktop, i.e. I want to change GNOME interface language. I run CentOS 6.3 on VMware Workstation 8 on Windows

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Each user can have his own language settings. So when a user goes to log in, the language changes to whatever language he used previously.

So for a user to change his language, he should first click his username in the list on the login screen, but do not type the password yet. Then go to the bottom center of the screen to change the language to the desired language he wants.

[image]